# gradlew build successfully by ssh but faild by php exec ERROR "Please set the JAVA_HOME variable" in CENTOS 7

Tags: php, centos7, gradlew

I set JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile and environment file.
when run gradlew by terminal in centos build seccessfull, but when run same command by php exec get JAVA_HOME ERROR

```
$command = "$path/gradlew -c $path/settings.gradle assembleRelease";
exec($command, $output, $code);
```

ERROR: "Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by send java_home in command string

```
$javaHome = "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161";
$command = "$javaHome $path/gradlew -c $path/settings.gradle assembleRelease";
exec($command, $output, $code);
```